# Getting error code 204144647 with message "The new service has can't be edited service,which can't be updated" from AppGallery Connect API

Tags: android, huawei-developers

I've used the [sample code of Huawei AppGallery's Connect API](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Examples/agcapi-publish_api_code) as base for automating app publishing. This is mainly going well, but is failing when trying to set an uploaded app bundle as draft.

These are the steps we are doing:

1. Getting a token
2. Getting app info
3. Uploading app bundle
4. **This step fails:** Updating "app file info"

The sample code's model classes seemed to miss a field for the `fileName` according to the [documentation for updating app file information](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-app-file-info_v2#h1-1576134669229-0) when uploading an app package, so I have added that.

When updating the file info I get the following error message back:
`{"code":204144647,"msg":"[cds]update service failed, additional msg is [The new service has can't be edited service,which can't be updated!]"}`

[The common result codes](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-returncode_v2) only describes this as *"Failed to update the service."*

What could the underlying problem be? And how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It turns out the operation of updating the file info was blocked by another app bundle being in review.**

**The same error is still present when the app has been approved, but is in a phased roll-out.** The moment the app is set to *"Full release"* and then get status *"Released"* it should be possible to update the file info and get a new app bundle into draft. Hopefully this will change so that it would be possible to have both an app in staged roll-out and preparing a new draft.

**Update:** The same day as I got that error code the list of software packages didn't update, the after the phased roll-out was at 100% all the uploads I thought to have failed was there in the list.

Comment: Yes, you can update the app file info after another app bundle being reviewed. By the way, have you solved your problem? If not, could you please provide your appid? I'd like to check it out.

Comment: @shirley Yes, the issue was solved. Thank you for your offer. It's great to see Huawei being this active on this site. :)